# How to open Side Menu from nested StackNavigator in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My navigation has a following structure:

```
StackNavigator
    Login
    PasswordReset
    Dashboard
        VehicleEnquiry
            VehicleDetails
```

MainRouter.js file:

```
const RootDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: DashboardScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: Dashboard,
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="home" style={styles.drawerIconStyle} />
      ),
    },
  },
  VehicleEnquiry: {
    screen: VehicleEnquiryScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Barcode Scanner',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="barcode" style={styles.drawerIconStyle} />
      ),
    },
  },
  Logout: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Login",
      drawerLabel: 'Logout',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="arrow-left" style={styles.drawerIconStyle} />
      ),    
      headerLeft: null
    },
  },
},

);

RootDrawer.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,   
  headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,  
});


const MainRouter = StackNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
   screen: RootDrawer,
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeNavigation,
  },
  VehicleEnquiry: {
    screen: VehicleEnquiryScreen,
  },
  VehicleDetails: {
    screen: VehicleDetailsScreen
  }
});
```

In the body of VehicleEnquiryScreen component I have added static navigationOptions just after the constructor of the class:

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Dashboard",
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.MainRouter.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); }} >
                <View style={styles.userImageBackground}>
                    <Icon name="bars" style={{ color: 'white', padding: 10, marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 20 }} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
    })
```

This is what I want to achieve:
I run the app and go straight to the Login screen. I sign in and go to the dashboard screen. From the dashboard I open left side menu and pick the option Vehicle Enquiry and go to this screen. I want to be able to open the side menu once again from the Vehicle Enquiry screen but when do this I just go to the previous screen instead of seeing the menu. 
From Vehicle Enquiry Screen I can go to the Vehicle Details Screen. I would also like to be able to open the side menu when I’m on Vehicle Details Screen.

I’ve tried many ways to solve this issue based on:

```
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers#Header-interaction-with-screen-component
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Cheers